# What are "discouraged blocks" in the blockchain? (examples and explanation please)

Tags: blockchain, development

As of the time I write this, only one [block type is marked as "discouraged"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Discouraged_block), and I'd like to understand why this exists.

- Is a correct reading that is that "it **should** be in the blockchain?
- Is this simply the block number embedded in the transaction?
- Are there any sample blocks that do or don't have this information?

Comment: The link states this: At the moment, the only "new rule" for which disobedience is being discouraged is the "put the block height in the coinbase" rule.
The way I read it, there is a rule "put the block height in the coinbase" and *disobedience* is discouraged. That would mean the opposite of what you state in the question title, which would mean that the block height is encouraged to be in the coin base. Disclaimer: I know little about this topic, but that's how I read it...

Comment: @HighlyIrregular I edited the question, I see that your interpretation may be spot on.  Now that my thinking isn't inverted, it makes sense, though I wonder how / why unnumbered blocks would ever work.  Was it a v0.01 bug?

Comment: See also http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/who-obeys-discouraged-blocks

Answer (score 1):

The wiki article you describe has been updated since by a skilled developer who is part of the Bitcoin team and the key change now reads:

> Bitcoin does not currently implement block discouraging in any form.

So this appears to be a concept that has not been implemented by any clients.